# pin_rel issue while loading rated events (Error: Update Stored Procedure: 8003)

Tags: oracle

I'm getting the following error while loading the .out file using pin_rel

```
Error 02/28/16 10:46:56:0552 PM ( 1456728416552 )  T:Update SP Thread 1 REL RELUpdaterThread 1:ece:UnknownProgramName:0:Update SP Thread 1:0:1456728416:0
RA-20003: Error -20015error while processing data from event_essentials occurred in the update procedure start_obj_id0 = 1449525761317588038 end_obj_id0 = 1449525761317588038 sqlcode = -20015 sqlerrm = ORA-20015: precommit failed (with exception): 18838741
ORA-06512: at "PIN10.PIN_REL", line 4260
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: DeterminateError - ERR_BAD_OPCODE
FList.java:0: ErrBuf Fields:
Error=ERR_BAD_OPCODE    Loc=DM
Field=PIN_FLD_OP_SQL_TRACE    Rec=0    reserved=35
Facility=0    MessageID=0    Time=4:00 PM    Version=0    Reserved2=0
Args=<none>
Nested Error:
<none>

ORA-06512: at "PIN10.PIN_REL", line 4898
ORA-20015: precommit failed (with exception): 18838741
ORA-06512: at "PIN10.PIN_REL", line 4260
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: DeterminateError - ERR_BAD_OPCODE

FList.java:0: ErrBuf Fields:
Error=ERR_BAD_OPCODE    Loc=DM
Field=PIN_FLD_OP_SQL_TRACE    Rec=0    reserved=35
Facility=0    MessageID=0    Time=4:00 PM    Version=0    Reserved2=0


Error 02/28/16 10:46:56:0571 PM ( 1456728416575 )  T:main REL IREL 1:ece:UnknownProgramName:0:main:1:1456728415:0
        Error encountered in the Update Stored Procedure: 8003
The update stored procedure encountered an error on an update statement.
Error 02/28/16 10:46:56:0575 PM ( 1456728416575 )  T:main REL IREL 1:ece:UnknownProgramName:0:main:1:1456728415:0
        Exiting with return code: 8
```

One of the suggestion was to execute below listed .plb files present in pin_rel directory

1. pin_rel_tt_pre_updater_sp.plb*
2. pin_rel_updater_sp_oracle.plb*
3. suspense_updater_sp_oracle.plb*
4. pin_rel_tt_updater_sp.plb*

But this solution didn't work. Only event related tables are loaded, Item tables aren't populated.

Comment: I think you'll probably need to raise a service request. Check on My Oracle Support to see if it's a known issue first, but I can only see 782612.1 which  is against a different line number and might be a different version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I was not able to find any solution there initially. Now I found the solution. I ll be adding that answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the `ObjectCacheTypeOutputSplit` to `FALSE` in pipeline registery. If this field is set to `TRUE` it will result in 2 identical output files from a single input EDR and write them to separate output streams.